# Punishing a couple to stop intercaste marriage is of which Karma(Good Or Bad)?

Tags: dharma, marriage, caste-system

- Inter-caste marriage is not appreciated by our scriptures and also in practical life and [Stopping a inter - caste marriage](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17148/is-stopping-an-inter-caste-between-a-brahmin-woman-and-a-shudra-man-dharma-or/17149?noredirect=1#comment44265_17149) is dharma and is of good karma.
- Couples get killed or beated by  their relatives if they have **No other way** to stop the marriage.

**QUESTION :**

- Does our **Scriptures** provide punsihments for commiting Inter-Caste marriage ?
- **Punishing** for misdeeds is applicable for a king and do their parents,brothers and relatives have right to punish them ?
- If a couples parents punish them for the Inter - caste marriage will they get **Bad karma** ?

Comment: Killing is a huge sin than committing an intercaste marriage. So the question is pointless. Couple should me made realise what they are lacking. Edit your question.

Comment: @SreeCharan thanks for answering but  you know making them realise is the first step all parents do and at last when there is NO OTHER WAY  then killing is performed and if they not kill them they will ran away and marriage so only i am asking in this kind of way

Comment: Yes that is not accepted. "Punishing a couple" would be more appropriate than "Killing a couple". So I asked you to edit your question.

Comment: @SreeCharan i edited my comment and i will edit the question also

Comment: @SreeCharan Is it correct now

Comment: you changed the question completely.. pls don't do that.

Comment: I reverted your edit because it's a totally different question than your original question; you should ask a new question re: cow dung.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Sakthi,while the Scriptures generally don't encourage inter caste marriages but nowhere such marriages are said to be as punishable offences.

In some cases (where the caste of the bridegroom is higher than that of the bride) such marriages are even allowed.

> A Brahmana can marry a Kshatriya or Vaishya girl; a Kshatriya can take
>   a Vaishya wife, and a Vaishya can wed a Sudra's daughter. But the
>   member of an inferior caste can not wed a girl of superior caste.
>
> **Vyasa Smriti,Chapter 2,verse 11.**

And punishment is not a bad thing either.Its  the fear of punishments only that stops offenders  from creating more crimes.

> Manu Smriti 7.22. **The whole world is kept in order by punishment**, for
>   a guiltless man is hard to find; **through fear of punishment the whole
>   world yields the enjoyments.**

And,it is even stated at one place that one of king's duties is to prevent the creation of inter-mixing of castes.

> Manu Smriti 8.172. By taking his due, **by preventing the confusion of
>   the castes (varna),** and by protecting the weak, the power of the king
>   grows, and he prospers in this (world) and after death

But , i have not found any punishments as such for couples who have inter-caste(varna) marriages.Punishments for inter caste adultery cases,however, are mentioned.

**So,punishing such couples by inflicting them with pain will be unlawful.**

.

Comment: @Sakthi After a cursory reading i cud not find any punishments as such..I'll make a more thorough search and let u know..And yes one of king's duties is to prevent creation of the varna sankaras..That's y punishments for adultery between different castes are strict..

Comment: It's a king's duty to stop inter-mixing of castes and he can verily punish. But here OP is asking whether he himself or someone similar shd do the job of punishing or not which I thought shd be discouraged. In today's time king=govt and the laws of govt do not prohibit intercaste marriages.. @NaveenKick

Comment: Not directly mentioned but mentioned indirectly as one of the duties of the king. One of the king's prime duties is to prevent the occurrence of confusion of castes. Death penalty might not be mentioned. Also thr r 18 Smritis and 18 Upasmritis too. Hv u gone through all of them? Yes we can reject Puranas whn it is clearly in contradiction with the Smritis. @NaveenKick

Comment: Ok I will chk.. not finding much time these days .. if u hv an online link then u can share it too here @NaveenKick

Answer (score 6):

Such punishment based on the spurious concept of last name based caste (not in Hindu scripture) violates basic tenet of Hindu ethics.

**Vidura on virtue**

> Vidura said, ‘Study of the various scriptures,
>   asceticism, gift, faith, performance of sacrifices, forgiveness,
>   sincerity of disposition, compassion, truth, self-restraint, these
>   constitute possessions of Virtue. Do thou adopt Virtue. Let not, thy
>   heart ever turn away from it. Both Virtue and Profit have their roots
>   in these. I think that all these are capable of being included in one
>   term. It is upon Virtue that all the worlds depend (for their
>   existence). It is by Virtue that the gods attained to their position
>   of superiority. It is upon Virtue that Profit or Wealth rests. Virtue,
>   O king, is foremost in point of merit. Profit is said to be middling.
>   Desire, it is said by the wise, is the lowest of the three. For this
>   reason, one should live with restrained soul, giving his attention to
>   virtue most. **One should also behave towards all creatures as he
>   should towards himself.**

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CLXVII

**Vidura on how to treat others**

> **That which is antagonistic to one’s own self, should never be applied
>   in respect of another.**

[Mahabharata, Udyoga Parva, Section 39]

**Bhishma’s morality**

> Bhishma said, **‘Knowing how painful it is to himself, a person should
>   never do that to others which he dislikes when done to him by others**.’

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLX

**Moral guidelines for the Righteous**

> Yudhishthira said, ‘Abstentions from injury, the observances of the
>   Vedic ritual, meditation, subjugation of the senses, penances, and
>   obedient services rendered to the preceptors - which amongst these is
>   fraught with the greatest merit with respect to a person?’
>
> Vrihaspati said, ‘All these six are fraught with merit. They are
>   different doors of piety. I shall discourse upon them presently. Do
>   thou listen to them, O chief of the Bharatas! I shall tell thee what
>   constitutes the highest good of a human being. That man who practices
>   the religion of universal compassion achieves his highest good. That
>   man who keeps under control the three faults, viz., lust, wrath, and
>   cupidity, ,,, (and practises the virtue of compassion), attains to
>   success. ……. **That man who regards all creatures as his own self, and
>   behaves towards them as towards his own self, laying aside the rod of
>   chastisement and completely subjugating his wrath, succeeds in
>   attaining to happiness. ….One should never do that to another, which
>   one regards as injurious to one’s own self.** This, in brief, is the
>   rule of righteousness.

Mahabharata Anusasana Parva Section CXIII

Comment: if my understanding is correct you are also referring ahimsa or treat others as you treat yourself. Is it correct or if i misunderstood it please explain to me clearly

Comment: Treating others as one would like to be treated is not the same as the idea of Ahimsa. Let us take an example in everyday life. You are a business man to whom a foreigner comes and wants some goods. You see that you can easily charge him a higher price taking advantage of his ignorance. You charge him the fair price because you don't want to be treated unfairly in a foreign land. Violence is not the issue here.

Comment: i am confused please  can you explain the relation between the question and your comment

Comment: i am not quick in uderstanding you said fariness because explain it with answer so i can understand

Answer (score 5):

> Inter-caste marriage is not appreciated by our scriptures and also in
>   practical life and Stopping a inter - caste marriage is dharma and is
>   of good karma.

First of all this statement is not true because vedas only talk about four वर्ण varan, which were on the basis of Karma not जाती.

So as per the highest book vedas inter-caste marriages can be done.

> Couples get killed or beated by their relatives if they have No other
>   way to stop the marriage.

We have no right to hurt other humans

> अहिंसा परमॊ धर्मस तथाहिंसा परॊ दमः।
>
> अहिंसा परमं दानम अहिंसा परमस तपः।
>
> अहिंसा परमॊ यज्ञस तथाहिस्मा परं बलम।
>
> अहिंसा परमं मित्रम अहिंसा परमं सुखम।
>
> अहिंसा परमं सत्यम अहिंसा परमं शरुतम॥

The above passage from Mahabharata emphasises the cardinal importance of Ahimsa in Hinduism, and literally means: **Ahimsa is the highest virtue, Ahimsa is the highest self-control, Ahimsa is the greatest gift, Ahimsa is the best suffering, Ahimsa is the highest sacrifice, Ahimsa is the finest strength, Ahimsa is the greatest friend, Ahimsa is the greatest happiness, Ahimsa is the highest truth, and Ahimsa is the greatest teaching.**

Above passage Source Wikipedia

One should himself honestly and the answer will be No you can not kill or beat other living being, other living being have the same feelings as other human being.

Comment: i added caste to be more easy to understand as caste is in our yuga , you can see the link it has answer with Manu smriti about inter caste marriage and personal suggestion dont refer wikipedia it is not trusted you can see hindu sites for answers and  last one punishment and harming are of different meanings.Punsihment is to bring one back to dharma path where as harming is to hurt one because of adharma thinking of other that hurts him and we cannot follow ahimsa fully as you mentioned mahabharatha, the mahabhartha  was a war and to destroy adharma punishing was done

Comment: you are right because we see it in the definition of god as well, which says god punishes and is merciful, which seems to be paradoxical but it is not.
See if two person want to marry means they are serious about it , if i am not wrong Lord Krishna himself helped his sister to marry Arjuna.

Comment: lord krishna and his sister were of kstriya varna and arjuna was also a kstriya so lord krishna did not appreciated inter caste marriage and  you are referring serious i cannot understand

Comment: @Sakthi You should at least know that Varna does not mean in which varna you are born, Varna were chosen by karma not by birth.

More Over Lets say you are a bharaman and your brother is selected in Indian army.

I hope its clear now

Comment: yes i am saying birth is by karma and level of karma(good or bad) decides varna and it is not appreciated to mix varnas and stopping mixing of varna is also dharma means punishing is of which deed good or bad

Comment: Rishi-The Vedas don't explicitly say if varnas are based on Karma or Guna or Birth..They simply mention them..The Smritis say all these play a part in determining the varna..with birth being the foremost factor..but samskaras,karma and guna also play important part..If varnas are not determined by birth then samskaras can't be performed..Also Shastras like Smritis are Veda Mulak..tht is they have Vedas as their roots..so for the most part they don't contradict the Vedas..So,if Smritis say varna is birth based the Vedas can't say otherwise..This is usually accepted..

Comment: Can you cite exact location of those verses in Mahabharata? Online sites say "Ahimsa paramo dharma, Himsa dharma tadaivacha" too but Mahabharata doesn't contain any such verse.

Comment: -1 You gave a direct assertion to the topic of Varna without consulting vedas and other scriptures, purvacharyas were not foolish to misinterpret vedas.You did not cite the exact vedic verse.

Comment: Rishi what's up? Long time no see??

Comment: @Rickross M good & you ? 
yes I lost my job and found a new one. This time not in Delhi. In a town. which is better in many ways than modern cities.
All over I am good. Thanks for caring .

Comment: @Rishi Ok good..enjoy ur stay in the new town then..I am good too..:)