# Do Vedas allow sacrificing innocent animals in the name of GOD?

Tags: vedas, yajna, sacrifice

This question has arises out of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17246/8883) answer and I want to know the truth because as per my knowledge several amendments have been made by pandits for their own benefits in past 4000 years, So how much truth can be in the statement that vedas allow us.

I know there are several pooja in which people give bali in the name of god.

Well on one hand vedas says so positive about be loving and on other how can it say to sacrifice the same animal for GOD.

Comment: It sounds like it is hypo critic.

Comment: There are no amendments whatsoever in samhita portions of shrutis. Vedas are apaurusheya and yajurveda describes process of ashewamedha and similar sacrifices which involves horse sacrifice

Comment: @Rishi how hypocritic?

Comment: @Rishi Vedic texts teach us that at core we are minute imperishible spirit souls. Anything that frees the conditioned soul from the material entanglement is of supremem benifit and must be done regardless of how much bodily austerity it may involve. So when a animal is sacrificed in a yagya, he attains higher consciousness(Human birth) or liberation. However animal sacrifice is forbidden in this age of Kali since there are no qualified people who can perfectly chant vedic hymns.

Comment: this is a duplicate of several questions. It will be closed.

Comment: Already answered. See Brahma Sutras 3.1.25. Sacrifice of animals is allowed.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda  swami ji first Brahma Sutra is not Vedas, and kindly provide the veda mantra

Comment: The Upanishads, the Bhagavad- Gita, and the Brahma Sutras are the three basic texts (prasthanatrayi) of Vedanta. To be orthodox Hindu means to accept these three texts as scripture.

Comment: See Manu Smriti V.22-44 for verses on sacrificing animals

Answer (score 7):

The answer of your question is given by **Shree-Krishna in Shreemad Bhagvat Maha Purana. ( Canto 11 ,Chapter 21 , Shlokas 29-30) SB 11.21: Lord Kṛṣṇa’s Explanation of the Vedic Path.** [**Here**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/21)

> ते मे मतमविज्ञाय परोक्षं विषयात्मका:।
>  हिंसायां यदि राग: स्याद्
>   यज्ञ एव न चोदना॥29॥
>  हिंसाविहारा ह्यालब्धै: पशुभि: स्वसुखेच्छया
>   ।
>  यजन्ते देवता यज्ञे: पितृभूतपतीन खला:॥30
>
> te me matam avijñāya parokṣaṁ viṣayātmakāḥ hiṁsāyāṁ yadi rāgaḥ syād
>   yajña eva na codanā hiṁsā-vihārā hy ālabdhaiḥ paśubhiḥ sva-sukhecchayā
>   yajante devatā yajñaiḥ pitṛ-bhūta-patīn khalāḥ
>
> **Meaning** - Those who are sworn to sense gratification cannot understand the confidential conclusion of Vedic knowledge as explained
>   by Me. Taking pleasure in violence, they cruelly slaughter innocent
>   animals in sacrifice for their own sense gratification and thus
>   worship demigods, forefathers and leaders among ghostly creatures.
>   Such passion for violence, however, is never encouraged within the
>   process of Vedic sacrifice.
>  [**SB 11.21.29-30**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/21/29-30)
>
> ---
>
> **Here is Swami Prabhupada's comentory on above shloka** -:
>
> **The Vedic scriptures sanction occasional animal sacrifice to satisfy
>   cruel, low-class men who cannot live without the taste of flesh and
>   blood.** Such concessions, however, are restricted by rigorous
>   obligatory rituals and are meant to gradually discourage animal
>   killing.
>
> **But unscrupulous persons misconstrue such restrictive sanctions and
>   declare that Vedic sacrifice is meant for killing animals in order to
>   enjoy sense gratification.** Although understanding the authority of
>   Vedic rituals, they do not accept the ultimate Vedic conclusion and
>   therefore never surrender to God. Thus false religious principles
>   flourish in the demoniac societies of the animal killers.
>
> ---
>
> So from above shlokas we can say that even though people are misinterpreting the meaning of  allowance of Vedic-sacrific in  limited manner ,  So in that sence ,**Yes ,Vedas allow  occasional sacrifice of innocent animal in Yagnas.** however, is never encouraged within the process of Vedic sacrifice.

**Note** - As said in the above shloka we must first understand ,why it is allowed in vedas.( for the people who cannot live without the taste of flesh and blood).

Answer (score 1):

No Vedas never say to sacrifice innocent animals.

1. Atharva-veda 7.5.5 says:

> मुग्धा देवा उत शुनायजन्तोत गौरडैः पुरुधायजन्त
>
> Meaning:  "Those are foolish who use meat of Dog and other animals in Yajna.

2. Mahabharat, Anusana parva 115.43: 116.45 says that those wretch people will go to hell those who slaughter creatures in the Yajna’s.