# What do Vedas say about non-sacrificial killing of animals?

Tags: scripture, vedas, culture, animals, non-vegetarian

Do Vedas or any scripture say anything about any restrictions on non-sacrificial killing of animals?

We all know about [animal sacrifices](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8882/2995) which was later explained by scholars.

But what about **normal (non-ritual) animal killing**, does it have any restrictions?

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17248/do-vedas-allow-sacrificing-innocent-animals-in-the-name-of-god/17250#17250

Comment: This is what MB says -http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b092.htm - check point no.3

Answer (score 7):

I am answering because the question's body has this " Do vedas or **any scripture**.. " in it.

> But what about normal animal killing do it have any restrictions?

As you may already expect, normal killing (that is other than when in sacrifices) is never recommended.

Lord Shiva says to Goddess:

> Pitridaivatayajneshu vaidha himsA vidhiyate |
>  **AtmArtham prAninAm
>   himsA kadAchinnoditA priye** ||
>
> ........
>
> In Yajnas, meant for Manes and Gods (Pitri Daiva Yajna), animal sacrifices are allowed. But
>   , **O Beloved one, for one's own sake (AtmArtham), killing animals (prAninAm himsA) are never
>   prescribed in scriptures**.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 1.45**

In fact, not only animals, even plantations should not be destroyed for our own selfish purposes, which he says in the very next verse:

> Swanimittam trinam vyapi chedayenna kadAchana |
>
> ....
>
> For one's own sake one should not even cut a grass.

In the Smritis, atonement measures are prescribed for killing different animals (If you want some such verses, i can provide). And, in them, we can find punishments too, being mentioned for the crimes one commits by destroying plants etc for no good reasons, for one's own selfish use.

Now, the same injunctions can be found in almost every scriptures.

For example, the Manu Smriti says:

> 5.38. As many hairs as the slain beast has, so often indeed will he who killed it without a (lawful) reason suffer  a violent death in
>   future births.
>
> 5.52. There is no greater sinner than that (man) who, though not worshipping the gods or the manes, seeks to  increase (the bulk of)
>   his own flesh by the flesh of other (beings).

And, as per it, the lawful reason is when the animal is sacrificed for Gods or Manes (Pitrus).

> 5.39. Svayambhu (the Self-existent) himself created animals for the sake of sacrifices; sacrifices (have been  instituted) for the good of
>   this whole (world); hence the slaughtering (of beasts) for sacrifices
>   is not slaughtering  (in the ordinary sense of the word).
>
> 5.40. Herbs, trees, cattle, birds, and (other) animals that have been destroyed for sacrifices, receive (being  reborn) higher existences.

So, normal killing of animals (or even of plants) for purposes other than sacrifices is never recommended in any scriptures. And, this is the conclusion of all scriptures.

Only exception obviously will be the case where the animal is threatening your life, in that case killing it out of self-defense is not a sin, since preserving one's life is the first priority.

Comment: but rickross i don't beleive in animal sacrifices great acharyas have rejected it mahabharat too reject it.;)

Comment: @Fiercelord Which great acharyas? Vedas prescribe animal sacrifice  and all other scriptures say that there is no sin attached to it.. So, they are allowed. But better not to do it now, as able performers of sacrifices are unlikely to be found now. Also, in Mahabharat itself Bhisma tells how manes remain gratified by sacrificing this animal that animal etc. So, Mahabharata certainly does not reject it.

Comment: If an animal is sacrificed to God or Mane exactly as prescribed in the scriptures and by able persons then that does good to the animal . The animal reaches higher heavens, so that's why it is not a sin. Killing otherwise is a sin. Because the animal is getting apaghAta mrityu (accidental and cruel death). and the same applies for plants. @Fiercelord

Comment: mahabharata says:—

 **Wine, fish, honey,
meat, alcohol, and preparations of
rice and sesame seeds, have been
introduced by knaves. The use of
these (in sacrifices) is not laid down
in the Vedas.** The hankering after
these arises from pride, error of
judgment, and cupidity. They that
are true Brahmanas realise the
presence of Vishnu in every sacrifice.
His worship, it has been laid down,
should be made with agreeable
Payasa. **(The leaves and flowers of)
such trees as have been indicated in
the Vedas,**
— The Mahabharata: Santi Parva: SECTION CCLXV

Comment: @Fiercelord Mahabharat at other places talk about animal sacrifices. Vedas clearly mention animal sacrifices at many places too. Also the Pandavas, who are the main characters of the epic, were all meat eaters. If you read the epic urself you can verify. So, animal sacrifices are allowed in scriptures but as said above nowadays should not be performed. I am for banning animal sacrifices by law. But then animal slaughter will still continue. So, for the animals (banning animal sacrifices) does not mean anything

Comment: @Fiercelord Sruti and Smriti both allow animal sacrifice. You can see few Smriti verses in my answer itself

Comment: Once again, hard to believe in the 21st century but it is out there on u-tube - an iyengar-type chap justifying animal sacrifice saying that the sacrificed animal has the chance of being born to a vaishnavaite in its next incarnation !!!!!

Comment: It maybe ILLEGAL - aren't you people going to wake up? https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/sep/02/india-court-bans-animal-sacrifice-hindu-temples  "Sacrifice causes immense pain and suffering to innocent animals. They cannot be permitted to be sacrificed to appease a god or deity in a barbaric manner," it said.

The court also questioned the reasons for animal sacrifices, saying such rituals "must change in the modern era".

The court was ruling on a petition brought by animal rights activists, who applauded the move on Tuesday as long overdue."

Comment: @SK Yes slaughtering an animal gives it pain. So that's why animals are not anymore slaughtered worldwide right? If 100 animals are non-sacrificially slaughtered, then the no. of those who are sacrificed will be 0.00000000001 or even less. BTW i am totally against animal sacrifice. But what about animal slaughter in general which are done otherwise?

Comment: OH so then you are not against animal slaughter in general. I am against it in general. Anyways, u do not need to worry. Because, as said earlier, the no. of animals which are killed in a Hindu sacrifice per year is nothing compared to the staggeringly huge no. of the same that are killed otherwise and all of them die a painful death after being raised up just to be killed. @SK

Comment: rickross - questions like whether plants can be killed are vexing and have no answers.  But animal sacrifice is GRATUITOUS CRUELTY - like bullfighting.

Comment: All the animal killing whether normally or sacrificiall is not good in my eyes because they are also like us in vedas we all are pashus we have one pashupatinath so when we can avoid cruelity we should.
And how much i know animal sacrifice is symbolic.

**AWGP** rigveda says that it is symbolization. And eating meat i am not so but i can not say about others they are free for there choice.;)

Comment: Yes i agree with you. I too don't like cruelty to animals. But since scriptures clearly allow it saying that it ultimately does good to the world (because sacrifice correctly done does benefit the whole world) and to the animal as well i don't have problems with it. @Fiercelord