# Whose translation of AV 7.5.5 is this?

Tags: animals, yajna, sacrifice, atharva-veda

A couple of answers on this site (e.g., [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37372/2995)) cite this translation of AV 7.5.5:

> Atharvaved 7:5:5:- All those are foolish who use cow, dog or any other animal in yajnas.

From [another answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20594/2995):

> Atharva-veda 7.5.5 says:
>
> मुग्धा देवा उत शुनायजन्तोत गौरडैः पुरुधायजन्त
>
> Meaning: Those are foolish who use meat of Dog and other animals in Yajna.

Whose translation are these answers quoting?

Comment: You could have commented underneath answers to ask OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The translation quoted by me [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37372) is based on [Sriram Sharma's Hindi translation of AV](http://literature.awgp.org/book/atharveda/v2.105). I translated it myself to English.

> Atharveda: Part-1
>
> काण्ड-७ सूक्त-८
>
> १७५४. मुग्धा देवा उत शुनायजन्तोत गोरङ्गैः पुरुधायजन्त |
>
> य इमं यज्ञं मनसा चिकेत प्रणो वोचस्तमिहेह ब्रवः ||५||
>
> ---
>
> **विवेकरहित यजमान, श्वान और गौ आदि पशुओं के अवयवों के द्वारा यजन करता है, तो यह अकर्म मूर्खतापूर्ण और निन्दनीय है।** जो मन के द्वारा यज्ञ की महान् प्रक्रिया को जानते हैं, ऐसे आत्म-यज्ञ को जानने वाले परमज्ञानी महापुरुष ही परमात्मा के स्वरूप को बतलाएँ ||५||

Comment: You may want to check [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54885401#54885401) :)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Thanks for providing this information