# Are humans meant to live only for 100 years?

Tags: life-span

Is it true that humans are meant to live only for 100 years.
Which scripture say this ? I would like to know if such thing is spoken by God ?

Comment: See the following too -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/35955/4732