# Does scripture uniformly agree with this citation from Parashara smriti?

Tags: caste-system, dharma-shastras, brahmins, smriti, shudra

Parashara Smriti 8.25 [says](https://archive.org/details/ParasharaSmriti/page/n71/mode/2up):

> 25. Even a Brahmin of a bad character deserves respect;
>   but not so a Shudra, even though his passions may
>   have been subdued by him. Who would quit a wicked cow,
>   and try to milk a docile female ass?

Are there other citations from scripture that disagree with this verse?

Comment: This is total interpolation by later brahmins, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vena_(Hindu_king) a Kshatriya was killed by curses of Brahmins because he turned evil. Use your common sense, the creation is based on Karmas, not some caste based reservation. Nothing is given for free neither human birth, nor respect, nor Moksha. One who does nothing is inert and real Shudra, while subduing passions makes a person yogi from whatever background one comes from. If you have done good Karmas in past birth and you are born Brahmin in this birth, you will be judged on Karmas of this birth, not previous.

Comment: I have answered dozen times, https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38113/16530 , https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36406/16530 with such logicless statements of Kaliyuga from interpolated scriptures, one can satisfy one's ego, but not the Omniscient God who knows everything and who has created the creation. Thats why India was slave for Britishers and Muslims for 500 years, because true Hinduism was replaced with such interpolated and logicless laws.

Comment: @ManuKumar You blame Brahmins for interpolation? Then why trust Hindu scriptures at all when the expounders are Brahmins?

Comment: @Ikshvaku do you know anything other than focusing on word Brahmin and Vishnu and Ramanujacharya, after all universe has infinite names and God other than these three,  Brahmin is just a title, society is of 4 varnas not one, just like head, shoulders, thighs and legs, God is one who is source of scriptures not mortal Brahmins. Scriptures are useless for one who knows Brahman, rather his revelations become scriptures. Cramming scriptures is just burden, understanding them is crux. Brahmins are not self born but mere humans, they are pershible with world, Brahman i.e. God is immortal.

Comment: Even Abrahamic societies(non-Indian countries) have revelations of God and religion, even if they are varnaless and dont have any brahmins

Comment: The "caste,caste,caste" posters @Manu Kumar are going to drive so-called "low caste" hindus into the arms of Christianity, Islam and Buddhism.

Comment: @Vidyut, that's probably because you have not met Hindus in India who hold the same opinion. It is not your nor my right nor duty to interpret scriptures into non-literal sense using our limited intellect. we simply parrot the opinion of acharyas who are way more intellectual and character than we can imagine. It is true that varna has been diluted today - brahmins who drink alcohol, don't learn vedas etc. do not deserve the title of brahmins. I'm pretty sure that most Hindus who you particularly refer to do not possess these vices.

Comment: @Vidyut, the 'brahmins' who do not hold absolutist views are probably your liberal 'social alcohol drinking' woke young adults in IT industry who have not been red-pilled yet.

Comment: @ram, or it could be that those youngsters have neither been red-pilled nor blue-pilled, and are only woke to the extent of being skeptical of scriptural infallibility? How are you able to draw such broadbrush conclusions as to the personal habits and beliefs of people whose religious convictions, or lack thereof, appear to be different from yours? I'm not even sure what the point of that cheap potshot was

Comment: @Vidyut, *"How are you able to draw such broadbrush conclusions as to the personal habits"* - it's not rocket science. let me give you an example from a recent experience - a commenter named Vidyut felt confident enough about his ability, to broadbrush conclusions about the location and sect of those who hold absolutist views. so it is natural to extend that ability to other commenters as well. hence other commenters are able to broadbrush conclusions about the behavior & actions of those who *don't* hold absolutist views. Easy ?

Comment: @Vidyut Brahmins drinking liquor is heavily censured by all hindu scriptures; it is a "mahapatakin": mortal sin along with killing a brahmin. One has to completely reject hindu scriptures to do these things.

Comment: @Ikshvaku, I'm not sure why you would think that is of interest to me given that I have not ventured,commentary on scriptural injunctions, or lack thereof, in regard to Brahmins and liquor. This is a complete digression and muddying of the waters on the part of the user ram. I have no further interest in prolonging this particular conversation with either of you. Thank you

Comment: A comment I had posted in this thread a couple of days ago has been deleted, presumably by the moderators, whereas a bunch of irate responses to my comment have been retained unmolested. Moderator bias?

Comment: being against orthodoxy (especially against the orthodoxy of one sect) is frowned upon at HSE @vidyut . don't get provoked by the provocateurs from this sect (it stands out a mile who they are ) and freely express what you want to express, but you should know how the game is played here..

Comment: @Vidyut, you started a complete digressing tangential water muddying, about how those who hold absolutist views must belong to a certain location and sect. then you complain when others start drawing conclusions about those who don't hold absolutist views. That's right, you should not have started this discussion in the first place. It's good that common sense has prevailed upon you to at least not prolong it.

Comment: @SK, that's right. The root of Hinduism is shastras, which by definition are orthodox. They have to set high standards so that people at least aspire to reach them.. you know 'aim for the stars, reach the moon' philosophy. Of course a stance against orthodoxy is a stance against scriptures is a stance against Hinduism. No wonder it will be frowned upon in a site dedicated to hinduism. You shouldn't be surprised at things that are natural.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03311.htm) edition of the Mahabharata, translated by K M Ganguly, contradicts the above citation.

> The Yaksha asked,--'By what, O king, birth, behaviour, study, or learning doth a person become a Brahmana? Tell us with certitude!' Yudhishthira answered,-'Listen, O Yaksha! **It is neither birth, nor study, nor learning, that is the cause of Brahmanahood, without doubt, it is behaviour that constitutes it. One's behaviour should always be well-guarded, especially by a Brahmana.** He who maintaineth his conduct unimpaired, is never impaired himself.
> **Professors and pupils, in fact, all who study the scriptures, if addicted to wicked habits, are to be regarded as illiterate wretches. He only is learned who performeth his religious duties. He even that hath studied the four Vedas is to be regarded as a wicked wretch scarcely distinguishable from a Sudra (if his conduct be not correct). He only who performeth the Agnihotra and hath his senses under control, is called a Brahmana!'**

**Addition**

We have another [scripture](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vajrasucika-upanishad-of-samaveda/d/doc217036.html) (vajrasuchika upanishad) also saying that one becomes a brahmana not by birth, but by his qualities.

> There are four castes—the brāhmaṇa, the kṣatriya, the vaiśya, and the śūdra. Even the smṛtis declare in accordance with the words of the vedas that the brāhmaṇa alone is the most important of them.
>
> Then this remains to be examined. What is meant by the brāhmaṇa? Is it a jīva? Is it a body? Is it a class? Is it jñāna? Is it karma? Or is it a doer of dharma?...
>
> To begin with: is jīva the brāhmaṇa? No...
>
> Then is the body the brāhmaṇa? No....
>
> Then is a class the brāhmaṇa? No. Since many great Ṛṣis have sprung from other castes and orders of creation—Ṛṣyaśṛṅga was born of deer; Kauśika, of Kuśa grass; Jāmbuka of a jackal; Vālmīki of valmīka (an ant-hill); Vyāsa of a fisherman's daughter; Gautama, of the posteriors of a hare; Vasiṣṭha of Ūrvaśi[2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vajrasucika-upanishad-of-samaveda/d/doc217036.html); and Agastya of a water-pot; thus have we heard. Of these, many Ṛṣis outside the caste even have stood first among the teachers of divine Wisdom; therefore a class is not the brāhmaṇa.
>
> Who indeed then is brāhmaṇa? Whoever he may be, he who has directly realised his Ātmā and who is directly cognizant, like the myrobalan in his palm, of his Ātma that is without a second, that is devoid of class and actions, that is free from the faults of the six stains[6] and the six changes,[7] that is of the nature of truth, knowledge, bliss, and eternity, that is without any change in itself, that is the substratum of all the kalpas, that exists penetrating all things that pervades everything within and without as ākāś, that is of nature of undivided bliss, that cannot be reasoned about and that is known only by direct cognition. **He who by the reason of having obtained his wishes is devoid of the faults of thirst after worldly objects and passions, who is the possessor of the qualifications beginning with śama[8], who is free from emotion, malice, thirst after worldly objects, desire, delusion, etc., whose mind is untouched by pride, egoism, etc., who possesses all these qualities and means—he only is the brāhmaṇa.**

**Addition 2**

Nor does the Lord distinguish anyone based on birth as Sri Ramanuja mentions in his commentary on bhagavad gIta 9.29.

> 9.29 I am the same to all creation. There is none hateful or dear to Me. But those who worship Me with devotion abide in Me and I do abide in them.

Commentary by Sri Ramanujacharya

> 9.29 Being a refuge for all, I am the same to all creation, be they gods, animals, men or immovables, who exist differentiated from the highest to the lowest according to their birth, form, nature and knowledge. **With regard to those seeking refuge, none is hateful because of inferiority in status by birth, form, nature, knowledge etc. No one is discarded as an object of odium. Likewise, it is not that one who has resorted to Me is dear to Me on account of any consideration like birth, status etc. That he has taken refuge in Me is the only consideration. The meaning is no one is accepted as a refuge for reasons like birth.** But those who worship Me as their sole objective I like, because I am exceedingly dear to them, and because they find it impossible to sustain themselves without My worship. **So they abide in Me, irrespective of whether they are exalted or humble by birth etc. They abide in Me, as if they possess qualities equal to Mine. I also abide in them, as if they are My superiors.**

Enough said.

Comment: @SK Looks like you have an agenda here. The scripture clearly says one becomes brahmana by behavior and not by birth. So also, one is a sudra by behavior.

Comment: @SK varna system =/= caste system. the user just showed above it is not based on birth but on qualities.take example of a school, there are is a administrative part, there is a non adminstrative part, there is teaching staff, there is non teaching staff. how do people get those assigned? based on their education etc. the same way it is.

Comment: but the number of occasions when varna was "earned" in scripture are very very few - like Vishwamitra earning the "brahmarishi" title.  ALL the semi-pious statements never really let go of the discriminatory underpinnings of varna or caste whatever you want to call it.  thats why people EVEN TODAY are calling for caste discrimination.

Comment: From the "enough said" at the bottom it appears to me that you are the user lazy lubber. @yAdRcchika

Comment: @Rickross Why would he delete his account and make another here?

Comment: @Ikshvaku, to avoid stereotyping by others.. any case, yAdRcchika, while you are correct that character defines brahmins, it is incorrect to say that character ALONE defines brahmins. You have to understand, that birth in current life is a consequence of character in previous life. If someone rose to the position of CEO, does that mean a janitor who has done MBA and is super-smart will be allowed to take part in board meetings - you have to have the pedigree to enter certain restricted areas, but that pedigree alone is not enough.

Comment: in logic terms, birth is necessary but not sufficient to be respected as a brahmin.

Comment: I don't know that but its him. Also many users in the past have also deleted their accounts and then created new ones (Anurag Singh, Naveen Kick are the 2 examples that come to my mind). So,its not that uncommon. @Ikshvaku

Comment: Also its not that he created a new account after deleting the lazy lubber account. Because the lubber account was active even [2 months ago](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/question-on-bounties) and this account yadrchika was created 11 months ago. So, both accounts were active at the same time. May be user found out that having sock puppets is risky and kind of illegal and hence decided to delete one or may be he had some other reasons. @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Rickross Go ahead and complain to the moderator if you think something "illegal" is being done.

Comment: No I have better things to do. I just guessed that you were previously lazy lubber. It was a comment of a casual nature based on my observation. Nothing to be too upset about. Also mods have all the tools to find out illegal activity done by sock puppets.So, I need not worry about that.. Also, I never thought or suggested that you will/have misuse/d your privileges by creating sock puppets. FYI having sock puppets is allowed as long as they are not voting each other etc @yAdRcchika

Comment: @Rickross Such comments of casual nature, as made by you, fall under the category of bazaar gossip.

Comment: @Rickross It can't be Lazy Lubber because in another comment he just said Vishnu is considered supreme. Lazy Lubber doesn't think that.

Comment: @ram It can't be Lazy Lubber because in another comment he just said Vishnu is considered supreme. Lazy Lubber doesn't think that.

Comment: @Rickross, the term sockpuppet carries a negative connotation on SE associated with vote manipulation et al. If what you are suggesting is true, this is simply a case of multiple accounts - each of which, in the general non-SE sense of the term, is a "sock puppet" given that Lazy Lubber is unlikely to be anyone's real life name. In keeping with the subject of this particular SE I'd say Lazy Lubber reincarnated as yAdRcchika!