# Marriage within the brahmin shakhas

Tags: marriage, brahmins

I did read another question about [marriage between different varnas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17148/17231) but my question is marriage between two different Brahmin shakhas allowed in the scriptures?

For instance two Brahmin communities one following Yajur Veda and the other Rig Veda? Or between a vaishnavite and a Gaud saraswath Brahman.. or a vaishnavite and a shaivite?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry I missed that Q. Thanks. - So in which case by whose customs or rituals should the marriage be performed. The reason I ask is because a person I know from an iyengar boy is marrying a gaud saraswath girl. The girls side is insisting that the marriage rituals must be according to their habits and traditions. They are Rig Veda. And the boy's father is unconvinced. He refuses to attend the marriage if the boy performs even a single ritual by their custom.

Comment: @hemambujavalli marriage is called kanya dhana here who is doing that only girls dad is doing that so whatever way that girls dad is giving that should be accepted. otherwise its not dhana its kanya apharana

Comment: But when the veda's are different, won't the boy then need to recite mantras from the Rig Veda? Is that ok?

Comment: So in that case the mangal suthra will be according to the girls custom or the boys.  Are there any textual references to quote the same?

Comment: See if you want there is always leeway here and there one manglasutra based on girls, you can have another manglasutra based on boy.. or request the girls dad that manglasutra will be according boys.. usually we in mandhva tradition have 2 manglasutra.. I don't know about yours but im deleting my earlier comment because it may deem offensive to somebody

Comment: @Hemambujavalli, it might be a cross-region issue. within same region e.g. tamilnadu, they won't have much problem with rig-veda & sama-veda marriage. usually the girl's side and boy's side both have their own bruhaspati purohit. while girl's side purohit does majority of rituals, boy's side can also participate for their own customs. i'm not sure about gaud-saraswat brahmins because north india and south india differ a lot in customs. some north indian brahmins even eat fish/meat, so.. the boy's father might have a point. better check with purohits

Comment: @ram, Yes it is as you say. But then you see the purohit on either side is only speaking supporting the respective sides. Well I was hoping there might some reference texts that might help talk to either side.